# If I transfer 'ONE DOLLAR' into your account, is it a 'FUNDS' transfer or 'FUND'?

Tags: word-meaning, plural-forms, singular

[Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fund_1) don't help me.

> fund [countable] -*an amount of money that has been saved or has been made available for a particular purpose.* **and** 
>   fund [plural] -*money that is available to be spent.*

Now, if I transfer **ONE DOLLAR** into your account, is it a *fund* transfer or *funds?* **And,** the sum is **not** for charity. It's merely a money-transfer which banks in India refer to as *fund transfer or funds transfer*. They have this option on netbanking sites.

Comment: Would you still be asking the question if I rewrote it as "if I transfer **'one hundred cents'** into your account,...?" rather than "if I transfer **'one dollar'** into your account,...?", leaving it otherwise identical? And let's not get started on different currencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Fund* and *funds* are two different words:

1. *Funds* is an indeterminate, uncountable amount of money or currency. (Def.n 2 in [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fund_1).)
2. A *fund* is a countable noun meaning a collection of money to be used as payment or capital towards a certain purpose; *account* is a rough synonym. It offers no indication of how much money has been collected. The plural of this word is *funds*. (Def. 1 in [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fund_1); def. 3 has the same meaning, just not necessarily about money.)

I've omitted the use of *fund* as a verb because it's not related to the question at hand.

A *fund* contains *funds*. For example:

> Accounting needs to know which of our *funds* (2, plural) provided the revenue for the purchase.
>   The petty cash *fund* (2); it didn't cost very much.
>   Will we have enough *funds* (1) remaining in that account to buy lunch for everyone?
>   If we don't, we will have to wait until after our client's *funds transfer* (1) has gone through.

I'm surprised to hear that Indian English refers to a general movement of money from one account to another as a *fund transfer*. British, Australian and American English call it a *funds transfer* or *transfer of funds*. This makes more sense semantically, because *fund transfer* seems to imply a change in ownership of the account rather than a movement of money.

For example (ignore the *electronic* bit, it's not relevant to our discussion and just makes the term easier to search): [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/electronic-funds-transfer), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/electronic+funds+transfer), [Australian bank](http://www.nab.com.au/personal/internet-banking/help/funds-transfer/create-a-funds-transfer). Additionally, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fund%20transfer,funds%20transfer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,fund%20transfer;,c0;.t1;,funds%20transfer;,c0) and [the Corpus of Global Web-Based English](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/) both indicate that *funds transfer* is more popular by a wide margin. GloWbE shows that India prefers *funds* 67 to 37, though Bangladesh prefers *fund* 40 to 21, and Ireland is tied with both at 30.

*Funds* (or *fund*) describes the type of *transfer*, and together they form a compound noun. See the linked Cambridge and Dictionary.com definitions above, again ignoring the *electronic* portions. This noun is countable, but the pluralization applies to *transfer*. For example:

> I processed seventeen funds transfers today.

Regardless of whether *fund* or *funds* is the term of choice, it should not be changed based on the amount of money being transferred, because the term never actually specifies a particular quantity of currency. The source or intended purpose of the money is also irrelevant, for the same reason: the term means nothing more than a simple movement of an unspecified quantity of money from one storage space to another.

Comment: I added *funds transfer* as Indian Banks refer to. But trust me, I've seen *fund transfer* as well. BTW, +1. Nice answer.

Comment: Sure; I included the additional information to clarify why someone might see both *fund transfer* and *funds transfer*. It's never because of pluralization. If you use *fund transfer*, don't switch it up to *funds transfer* (the same holds for changing in the other direction). The amount, purpose and source of the money don't make any difference to the term.

Answer (score 2):

If you transfer one dollar from the charity fund to the recycling center, it would be:

> I **transfered funds** from the **charity fund** to the recycling center.

or

> I made a **funds transfer** from the **charity fund** to the recycling center.

A *fund* is some group of money, while *funds* are money upon which some action is taken, as it indicates in the definitions.

The usage you found may be a localized usage or just wrong. Maybe its safer to say *money transfer* instead as the meaning is more clear.

Comment: what is if I transfer one dollar into your account simply for no reason?

Comment: @MaulikV the number of dollars is irrelevant; and the reason is irrelevant also. There might be some local language or style reasons for preferring *fund* vs *funds* in a particular usage, but in all such cases one dollar would be the same as two dollars, and the reason wouldn't affect it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a dictionary reference to back me up, but I would say it is still "funds" purely because the amount of money that was transferred is indeterminant

Comment: clarified further. Kindly revise your answer.

Comment: i support what Esoteric Screen Name said :)